# Background image not showing on .bg class element

Tags: html, css, background-image

I want to add a parallax scrolling effect to the `.intro-body` of my home-page in the same way that I have added this effect to the jumbotron images I have on my 'About', 'Resume' and 'Portfolio' pages. For some reason however the background image doesn't show when I apply it to the `.bg` class. The images show correctly on the other pages; the only difference is that I'm using `#intro` before `.bg` which I have done so that I can style this image to fit the entire height and width of the screen.

The `background:` CSS property is showing an image in the below fiddle, but I can't get it to work on my own website:

https://jsfiddle.net/c3do6hj0/

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? I've spent about 3 hours researching on SO but to no avail, so any ideas are much appreciated, thanks

[My homepage](http://www.jonhowlett.uk)

HTML

```
<header class="intro" id="intro">
<div class="bg"></div>
    <div class="intro-body">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <h1 class="brand-heading">Jon Howlett</h1>
                    <p class="intro-text">Aspiring web designer<br/>&amp;<br/>front-end developer</p>
                    <a href="#summary" class="btn btn-circle page-scroll">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animate">    </i><span class="zero">Button Down</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
#intro .bg {
background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/common/5/57/LA_Skyline_Mountains2.jpg") no-repeat scroll center bottom / cover;
background-size: cover!important;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 1000px;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index: -1;    
}

.intro-body {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
padding: 100px 0px;
text-align: center;
color: #FFF;
background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: On your homepage there is an inline-style on the `.bg` div that is giving it `height: 0px;` is that on purpose?

Comment: It shows up for me on Chrome/Win7

Comment: @sethflowers he has the `background` image set on the div below the `.bg` div. That is why you can see it, but he is saying he can't get it to work on the `.bg` div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an inline style on the `.bg` div: `height:0px;`.

If i add the `background: #000 url("images/intropage_mountains.jpg") no-repeat scroll center bottom / cover;` to the `.bg` div then disable the inline style the background image shows up.

It appears that something in one of your javascript files is applying this inline-style.

When i change the class to something else such as `bg_main` the inline-style goes away and the background image works.

EDIT*: As a side note. I noticed that you have 2 different versions of jquery resourced.

`http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js`

and

`http://www.jonhowlett.uk/js/jquery.js`

I would advise you to only keep the latest version. having more than one jquery resource can sometimes cause conflicts with your code.

Comment: Thanks for your help here